# Update query sqlite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm not able to crack a simple Update query in SQLite in my android app.. here is the query,

```
int fav = 1;
Cursor c = sqliteDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ MyConstants.TABLE_NAME + " SET "+MyConstants.TABLE_NAME+"."+MyConstants.ISFAV+ " = "+fav+ " WHERE " +MyConstants.TABLE_NAME+"."+MyConstants.WORD_NAME+ " = \""+word_name+"\"", null);
```

Here is the exception,

```
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE words SET words.isfavor = 1 WHERE words.word = "hello"
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
07-06 23:41:48.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep using the table name inappropriately.  It should be more like this:

```
int fav = 1;
Cursor c = sqliteDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ MyConstants.TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ MyConstants.ISFAV + " = "+fav+ " WHERE " + MyConstants.WORD_NAME + " = \""+word_name+"\"", null);
```

which should give you a resultant query that looks more like this:

```
UPDATE words SET isfavor = 1 WHERE word = "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `UPDATE` statements always have only one table, so prefixing column names with table names would be meaningless and is not allowed.
2. In SQL, strings are delimited with `'`.
   `"` is used for identifiers like column names; your query will blow up when you try to handle the word `word`.
3. To avoid string formatting problems, you should use parameters:

```java
    sqliteDB.rawQuery("UPDATE ... WHERE word = ?",
                      new String[] { word_name });
```